# Flutter mediaItem.duration and playback speed design

Tags: flutter, dart, playback, duration

I am trying to build an app using Flutter and Dart. I hope to combine or place the mediaItem.duration bar and playback speed very closely like shown in the screen shot (the playback speed is the chinese character in the screenshot). Any suggestions on how can I achieve this layout? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this layout using the combination of stack and Positioned.